# Is there any filter space characterization for strong cardinals?

Tags: logic, set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

The theory of filter spaces is introduced by Apter, Diprisco, Henle & Zwicker, in their joint paper:

> *Arthur Apter, Carlos Di Prisco, James Henle, and William Zwicker*, [**Filter spaces: towards a unified theory of large cardinal and embedding axioms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(89)90009-2), *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **41** (1989), no. 2, 93--106.

They introduced filter space characterizations for large cardinals like measurable, supercompact and huge.

> **Question:** Is there any filter space characterization for strong cardinals?